# NODE_PATH no effect

Tags: node.js

I would like that

```
~ $ npm install express"
```

will not install express in my home folder, but instead in `~/apps/node_modules`.

So I inserted this `export NODE_PATH=/home/a/apps/node_modules` in `.bashrc` and than I did `source .bashrc`.

Unfortunately, `npm install express` still installs it in `/home/a/node_modules` and `npm install -g express` require root/Administrator.

How is it possible that npm install packages in `/home/a/apps/node_modules`?

Comment: Did someone install npm as root? npm install -g should never need to elevate root/admin rights. By default npm isntall is going to install in a directory called node_modules in the current working directory. It sounds like you're trying to achieve a global install without using -g.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NODE_PATH` is used to find modules, but not to install them.

You can use `--prefix` to signify where `npm` should install a package:

```
npm --prefix ~/apps install express
```

You could make it more permanent by configuring `npm` to always use that prefix, but that would only overwrite the *global* location. So you would need to use the `-g` flag:

```
# config once
npm config set prefix ~/apps

# after that, '-g' will install packages in ~/apps
npm install express -g
```

Also, using `-g` will install packages in `~/apps/lib/node_modules` (which, I think, cannot be changed), so add that directory to your `$NODE_PATH` as well.

Another solution would be to create a shell alias for `npm`:

```
# in your ~/.bashrc
alias npm="command npm --prefix ~/apps"
```

Although I'm not entirely sure how that would work together with `-g`.